# jQuery resize event - bug with mobile Chrome & FF

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, mobile, responsive-design

So apparently Google and the employees at Firefox think it's ok to resize the browser window when the keyboard pops up. Long story short, I have a resize event in my jquery.

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {

        if($("#wrapper").width() < 568)
            {           
                // Snap content to mobile
            }
        else
            {
                // Snap content back to full view          
            }

    });
```

This works 100% in Mobile Safari, and in all non mobile browsers but IE of course.

Here's the issue Chrome/FF are causing. When you select a form field the keyboard pops up and chrome / ff actually resize the window causing the .resize() event to be triggered which automatically hides the keyboard back as the field selected loses focus.

Anyone know of a way around this? This BTW is a browser issue, not an android one.

Thanks!

Comment: so it might be actually an issue with Android after all, since the underlying system is responsible for showing a virtual keyboard - or am I thinking wrong? is it happening in Opera, too? this just popped into my mind as I read that it's 100% ok in Mobile Safari... on iOS, right?

Comment: No, i downloaded chrome onto my iPhone and it causes the same problem.

Comment: Yes, they keyboard is part of the OS but the browser window is what reacts improperly to it showing up.

Comment: Did you find the solution to that issue yet? I'm having exactly the same one

Comment: Yes I did Pejs, although i wouldn't call it a fix. I simply changed my responsive breakpoints to 768, anything below is a phone and anything above is responsive not adaptive. Building mobile first led me to this somewhat accidental solution. Otherwise it's not something we can fix as far as i know. Good Luck!